# Ctrl + Shift + e to type é

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In Windows, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> types an é (British keyboard layout - EN UK). I use this quite a lot despite being an English speaker - most commonly to type 'Pokémon' and 'café'

In Linux this shortcut doesn't seem to exist. I know I can achieve the same thing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but this takes considerably longer.

How can I enable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the "*English (UK, extended WinKeys)*"  layout instead. You'll be able to type "**é**" by simply pressing "level 3 select key" and <kbd>e</kbd>. The level 3 select key is usually <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (right-<kbd>Alt</kbd> key).

Comment: This also works in US international layout

Comment: @SebastianStark Yes, I mentioned the UK one as OP uses EN UK layout now.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by pressing <kbd>right alt</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>

That is: Hold right alt key, press the key with `;:,"` on it, release alt key, press <kbd>e</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in the end I used the `English (international, dead keys via AltGr)`. I hope this helps other people finding this question.

Regardless, I wish you a beautiful day!